# Finding derivative for multiple chain rules in one problem

Tags: calculus

> Find the derivative of
>   $$y=\sqrt{e^{-3t^2}+5}$$

There seems to be several layers to this. I'm not quite sure how to go from one to the next.

Comment: How far did you get?

Comment: Are you familiar with chain rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unpack it as you would the order of operations.  Which operation is evaluated first, second, third, etc?  Once you have the operations ordered, you can perform the chain rules one at a time going from the outer-most operation to the inner-most operation.

Another way of thinking about this is start by only considering the most external operation, and try to evaluate its derivative.  When you run into a complex (read: hard to deal with) expression, just replace it with a temporary function and continue as you normally would.  Then, in order to evaluate the full derivative, you will have to evaluate the derivative of your temporary function.  When evaluating its derivative, you may or may not come across another complex expression.  Rinse and repeat until there are no more complex expressions anywhere.

I'm opting not to do this for you in your provided example, but rather answer your question of how to go from one chain rule to the next.  Hint: define your first temporary function as

$y_2(t) = e^{-3t^2}+5$

and try and solve the derivative

$y(y_2(t)) = \sqrt{y_2(t)}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1) $y=\sqrt{x} $ then $dy/dx = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$.

2 $y=e^{ax^b}$ then $dy/dx = e^{ax^b}\cdot abx^{b-1}$.